# pppoeconf login problem

Tags: networking, wifi

I used `pppoeconf` command for setup a `pppoe` connection over the `wireless` in `xubuntu 14.4` and follow all the steps based on ubuntu pppoe wiki but after run `pon dsl-provider` i cant connect to internet it raise `bad user name and password` error ! also i see them correctly in `chap-secrets`.

and im sure that my username and password are correct because i can connect with them quickly with `DSL` connection ! this is the plog Demo :

```
Oct  2 00:26:31 user_name  pppd[2446]: Connected to d4:ca:6d:77:4b:b4 via interface wlan0
Oct  2 00:26:31 user_name  pppd[2446]: Using interface ppp0
Oct  2 00:26:31 user_name  pppd[2446]: Connect: ppp0 <--> wlan0
Oct  2 00:26:31 user_name  pppd[2446]: CHAP authentication failed: bad username or password
Oct  2 00:26:31 user_name pppd[2446]: CHAP authentication failed
Oct  2 00:26:31 user_name pppd[2446]: Connection terminated.
```

does any body know whats the problem ?

this is my `interfaces` file :

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback



auto dsl-provider
iface dsl-provider inet ppp
pre-up /sbin/ifconfig wlan0 up # line maintained by pppoeconf
provider dsl-provider

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
```

and this is the end of `dsl-provider` :

```
plugin rp-pppoe.so
nic-wlan0
user "********"
usepeerdns
```

Comment: The username and password is incorrect.  Contact your ISP, and verify that they are correct, [or do what I asked you to do in your original question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158226/pppoe-connection-using-wifi-connection-in-linux), and connect your machine wirelessly to your router so you don't knock off the other people connected properly in Windows.  For the last time, YOUR ROUTER/MODEM SHOULD BE IN CHARGE OF THE PPPoE, not your OS!!!!  Remove pppoeconf.

Comment: as i say already im sure that my username and password are correct because i can connect with them quickly with `DSL` connection !!! i found the way to restore my connection if it lost after using `pppoeconf` now py problem is this !!!

Comment: Can you tell me the type of DSL modem you have, and I will help you connect it properly.  You're not understanding that your username and password are stored inside your modem.  As such, the only thingg you ned to do is connect your Wireless Card to the DSL Modem.

Comment: our modem is `D-Link` and the isp change our line to bridge mode ! therefor all of us need to connect with `pppoe` so when i connect with cable (`DSL` connection in linux networking ) and i type my user and pass i dont have any problem and connect easily !

Comment: every thing i want is able to create a `PPPOE` connection over `WIFI` do you have any idiea? do you know any app ?

Comment: also thanks alot for time ! and advise ! <3

Comment: maybe ! so is it possible that other user have pppoe and i have another connection type ? we have to get several id !

Comment: no, listen to me.  Is there a DLink connected to your modem or is the modem a DLink?  If the Dlink is a Router, connected to a modem, login to the DLink and Set the connection type to PPPoE.  If the modem is the Dlink, turn off the Bridging, turn on the Routing and set it to connection type PPPoE.  Can you give me the model of your DLink?

Comment: our router is Dlink i can connect to it with `192,168,0,0,1` and change the setting but **as i say we need several account** ! and i think we need to tell this to our ISP and it must change our connection type on server first !!! and if i change the modem config i destroy others account too ! we need separate account !

Comment: Give me a model number...  Turn it over and look for numbers like 2560 or 3000 etc. Does the Router have antennas?

Comment: model is `DSL-2730U ` yes it have antennas !

Comment: Dont Do anything Else Look for my answer in about half an hour!!!

Comment: Watch [this Youtube Video](http://youtu.be/cSMKl_Yt6cg), as it will take me awhile to put it into words.  Also, read [Step 9 Only Here](http://www.techlineinfo.com/configuration-guide-of-adsl-wifi-modem-d-link-dsl-2730-u-for-bsnl-and-mtnl/)

Comment: Answer Posted.  Feel free to ask questions.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need to do, as using 4 accounts will cost you extra, cannot be used at the same time, and may be illegal in your AUP anyway.

1. Disconnect All Computers from the Internet.
2. Remove All PPPoE Connection Software from all computers.
3. Find the Ethernet Cable that came with your Router.
4. Disconnect the DSL Cable from the DSL Port
5. Disconnect the Power from the Router.
6. Turn the Router bottom side up, and hold the reset button in for at least a minute, while the power is disconnected.
7. Plug in the Power and Boot the Router.  The DSL light should be blinking as the DSL port is unplugged.
8. Connect the Cable from Step 3 into Ethernet Port #4.  The Yellow Port numbered 4.
9. Open a web browser, and in the Address Bar type 192.168.1.1.  Use the Username admin and the Password admin.
10. You should see a webpage similar to the following:
    [image: Router Home Screen]
11. On the Setup Screen, Click Advanced Setup.
12. If there isn't already a row, Click the Add button.If a row exists, skip to step 14.
13. Fill in the following settings:
    VPI, VCI, and Encapsulation: Use [this table](http://www.speedguide.net/articles/adsl-vpi-vci-and-encapsulation-settings-2786).  If your ISP isn't listed contact your ISP and ask for these settings. Click Apply/Save.
14. Still on the Advanced Setup Menu from Step 11, Click WAN Setup, and then the Add button.
15. The Dropdown Box should contain the item you saved in step 13.  Click Next.
16. Bubble in PPPoE, and name the connection ppp_default.  Click Next,
17. Fill in your username and password here. The one you swear is correct.  **If it isn't correct, you must come back to this screen, and update it here only.  Nowhere else!!**  For Service name type the name of your ISP.  Click Next.
    [image: PPPoE Settings Screen]
18. Select DNS Server Interface from available WAN Interfaces. ppp_default should be listed in the left box. Click Next.
19. Click Apply/Save
20. From the Home Screen in Step 10, Click Wireless.
21. Check Enable Wireless.  Fill in the ESSID. Click Apply/Save.
22. Still on the Wireless Tab, Click Security. Disable WPS, and in the Manual Setup, choose the ESSID you created in step 21.  Choose your desired Security method in the Network Authentication, and fill in the required fields.  Write Down all Wireless Settings before clicking Apply/Save.
23. Close the Browswer. Turn off the Power. Disconnect the Ethernet Cable from Port 4, and Reconnect the DSL Cable. Reboot
24. Wait for the DSL light to go solid, and then reconnect all the Wireless Devices in your network, using the settings you wrote down in Steps 21 and 22.  For your Linux Box, connect `wlan0` to the ESSID.  For Windows use the Icon in the Taskbar.
25. Store your settings in a Safe place.

---

You should now be able to browse the internet using only 1 PPPoE account without any extra connection software, so you can safely remove ppoeconf using your package manager plus the software you used in Windows(Step 2).  Doing it this way, you only have to pay for one account, which is shared among the 5 of you.  Anytime you update the password for the account you used in Step 17, you must change it using Step 17 again, hence the bolding.

**REFERENCES:**
[Configuration guide of ADSL WiFi Modem D Link DSL 2730 U for BSNL and MTNL](http://www.techlineinfo.com/configuration-guide-of-adsl-wifi-modem-d-link-dsl-2730-u-for-bsnl-and-mtnl/)
[D-Link DSL-2730U User Manual](http://setuprouter.com/router/dlink/dsl-2730u/manual-1648.pdf)

Comment: When it Works, be sure and mark it correct...

Comment: Hi,i say your solution to my friends , so if we want to do such thing , we need a application for windows for store the used traffic ! do you know any good app ?